# Weird user-defined function behavior in Octave

Tags: function, octave

In Octave why does my function here always return `1`?

Code:

```
function val = g2(x)
     sigma = 0.1;
     if (x <= -8)
       val = exp(-0.5*((x+8)^2)/(sigma^2));
     endif
     if (x >= 8)
       val = exp(-0.5*((x-8)^2)/(sigma^2));
     endif
     if (-8 < x < 8)
       val = 1;
     endif
endfunction
```

Comment: You need to use python if you want `-8 < x < 8` to do what you expect it to do. It's also good practice to use if-elif-else whenever possible.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні I wonder. There's a great many languages that support this particular syntax. Why python in particular?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou because Python is the only language I'm familiar with that has operator chaining. Which is not a very strong statement, mind you. But it does rule out C, C++, fortran, bash, awk, latex, MATLAB, Octave and perl. I know nothing about java*, C#, haskell, prolog and others, so your mileage may vary. Which other languages do you know for this list?

Comment: Out of the ones typically considered as "alternatives to matlab/octave", the most prominent examples would be mathematica and julia, but there are several others (perl is actually one of them).

Answer (score 0):

`-8 < x < 8` is evaluated as `(-8 < x) < 8`, which is either `true < 8` or `false < 8`, depending on the value of `x`. Both of which are true, because `false` is 0 in a numerical situation, and `true` is 1. So the last conditional statement is always executed. In Octave you’d write `(-8 < x) && (x < 8)`.

But better would be to write your code as

```
function val = g2(x)
     sigma = 0.1;
     if x <= -8
       val = exp(-0.5*((x+8)^2)/(sigma^2));
     elseif x >= 8
       val = exp(-0.5*((x-8)^2)/(sigma^2));
     else
       val = 1;
     endif
endfunction
```